# What's the fastest way to get all the initial values of a variable? JS

Tags: javascript, html, variables, javascript-objects

I want to get the initial values (What I first defined it to be) of all the properties for one of my objects.

I want to do this at the "end" of my game.

I could just copy and paste the properties but the object is pretty big and im wondering if this would slow the site down a bit?

Thanks!

Code example:

```
var MyObject = {

    nestedObject1 : {
        //...
    },

    nestedObject2 : {
        value1 : "Hi",
        value2 : 1
    },

    objectProperty : 2637

}
```

How would I get all (Or maybe excluding one of the nested objects) of the properties to their intial value?

Comment: There is no way to obtain the initial value of a variable in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite fully understand how you want to get the initial values, at the end of your running. But probably the easiest way to do this is to just serialize your object to JSON using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
var original = JSON.stringify(myObject)
```

Then at the end of your application when you want access to this original object again you can rehydrate it to a new JavaScript object:

```
original = JSON.parse(original);
```

Comment: Does this create a new object? I cant really use that because all of my code is already written with one object. My real object has lots of vectors for a balls movement. The vectors change at 60fps with gravity. I need to get the initial object properties every few seconds.

Comment: Yes this will end up creating a clone of the original object. The advantage here is that you don't need to handle it field by field, and if you so wish you can define custom serialization rules to ignore certain fields during the serialization or deserialization step.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without creating a clone?

Comment: Not unless you guarantee the properties are not going to be changed. If you change one of the values then you'd be stuck, as the original value is no longer there - so instead you need to store your initial state somehow which is essentially a clone.

Comment: If I can't create a clone, would the best way to do this be to just define the object again?

Comment: @Manu: If you just define the object again, that is a clone.... It's just then you have to manually copy all the property values over 1 by 1. There's absolutely no way you can change an object and compare it to the original without somehow creating a clone of it in the first place. I've just provided the simplest way to create this clone for you.